# Possible to show PDF over a PageViewController in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I am developing a mobile app in which I need to highlight PDF text after searching and I am using PDF kitten library for this.

Library link: https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten

From this I got number of selections on the PDF as well as the content of the PDF but I am unable to highlight text as the PDF is loaded on the webview. Is this possible, to add my PDF document over pageview controller and highlight text over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a new instance of the scanner.

```
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
Scanner *scanner = [Scanner scannerWithPage:page];
```

Set a keyword (case-insensitive) and scan a page.

```
NSArray *selections = [scanner select:@"happiness"];
```

Finally, scan the page and draw the selections.

```
for (Selection *selection in selections)
{
    // draw selection
}
```

and then highlight the selections using core graphics framework.